# Meaning of the phrase "as measured by"

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> More fine-grained analyses compared the type of intellectual ability and the impact of age and social status, **as measured by** income and that all-important automobile.

Namely I cannot understand what "as" means there. Could anyone rephrase it for me please?

Comment: When we use income and automobile as the metrics of "social status".

Comment: It is very disappointing that after the moderation team spent a lot of effort explaining to you how much effort the community is putting into editing your posts for you that you continue to post the same poorly formatted questions with no explanation of the research that you have done in your attempts to answer your question.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I cannot format questions properly because my tablet doesnt enable me to do that

Comment: If you can type, you can format your posts. See the [Formatting Sandbox post on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2923/) for some tips and a place to practice posting and the [editing help page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Now what seems to be the problem with [telling us where you found your sentence](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/) and adding "the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is unclear, but as written I assume *social status* was measured by *income* and *automobile ownership*, since I don't see how those factors relate to age or intellectual ability.

Example:

> The study tracked the relationship between high school graduation rates and *nutrition*, **as measured by** whether the students *regularly ate a healthy breakfast*.

Comment: I think the text could be made clearer by discarding the comma which tends to separate the only credible target *(social status)* from the associated proxy measurements *(income/car ownership)*. Maybe *add* a comma after ***age*** to increase separation of that from the following term, so we're not tempted to apply the final clause to both. And to really spoon-feed the reader, repeat ***of*** before ***social status*** to "isolate" it even more.

Comment: Although it might be unclear in some ways, this comma structure is common in science writing and if I were editing I would still suggest the comma, since it's meant as somewhat of a parenthetical.